# Angular JS ng-click not responding only on iPad, works fine on Desktop

Tags: angularjs, radio-button, angularjs-ng-click

I am testing a web app on iPad. Everything works fine on desktop and even on desktop touch (Windows 8 machine with touch enabled), but when I get to iPad, the touch event is not firing at all times. It fires intermittently, but not always. Sometimes the ng-click does not work at all. Here is the code:

Models:

```
$rootScope["bBoxProps"] = [{
    "bType": "sBusinessType",
    "id": "sBusinessType",
    "title": "business",
    "options": [
        {
            "optId": "nyi",
            "name": "NYI",
            "isSelected": false,
            "isDisabled": false,
            "isInvalid": false
        },
        {
            "optId": "local",
            "name": "Local",
            "isSelected": false,
            "isDisabled": false,
            "isInvalid": false
        }
    ],
    "disabled": false,
    "invalid": false
},
{
    "bType": "sMediaBuy",
    "id": "sMediaBuy",
    "title": "buy type",
    "options": [
        {
            "optId": "audience",
            "name": "Audience",
            "isSelected": false,
            "isDisabled": false,
            "isInvalid": false
        },
        {
            "optId": "spot",
            "name": "Spot",
            "isSelected": false,
            "isDisabled": false,
            "isInvalid": false
        }
    ],
    "disabled": true,
    "invalid": false
},
{
    "bType": "sMediaDelivery",
    "id": "sMediaDelivery",
    "title": "media type",
    "options": [
        {
            "optId": "optimizedLinear",
            "name": "Optimized Linear",
            "isSelected": false,
            "isDisabled": false,
            "isInvalid": false
        },
        {
            "optId": "addressable",
            "name": "Addressable",
            "isSelected": false,
            "isDisabled": false,
            "isInvalid": false
        }
    ],
    "disabled": true,
    "invalid": false
}];
```

View:

```
<div class="buyBox" id="{{bBox.id}}" ng-repeat="bBox in bBoxProps" ng-class="{disabledBb: bBox.disabled, invalidBb: bBox.invalid}">
  <div class="bbTitle"><h3>{{bBox.title | uppercase}}</h3></div>
  <div class="bbSelect">
    <div class="bbSelectTop bbSelectOpt">
      <input type="radio" name="{{bBox.id}}" id="{{bBox.options[0].optId}}" class="css-checkbox" ng-click="pmFlow(state,this,bBox.options[0])" ng-checked="bBox.options[0].isSelected==true" ng-model="bBox.options[0].isSelected" ng-disabled="bBox.options[0].isDisabled" ng-class="{invalidBbOpt: bBox.options[0].isInvalid}" ng-value="true"/>
      <label for="{{bBox.options[0].optId}}" class="bbLabel"><div class="bbLabelText">{{bBox.options[0].name}}</div></label>
    </div>
    <div class="buyOr">OR</div>
    <div class="bbSelectBottom bbSelectOpt">
      <input type="radio" name="{{bBox.id}}" id="{{bBox.options[1].optId}}" class="css-checkbox" ng-click="pmFlow(state,this,bBox.options[1])" ng-checked="bBox.options[1].isSelected==true" ng-model="bBox.options[1].isSelected" ng-disabled="bBox.options[1].isDisabled" ng-class="{invalidBbOpt: bBox.options[1].isInvalid}" ng-value="true"/>
      <label for="{{bBox.options[1].optId}}" class="bbLabel"><div class="bbLabelText">{{bBox.options[1].name}}</div></label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

There are some functions that are supposed to run upon tap of the label/input "bbLabel" .. But the ng-click fires only on two or three taps of the label. This is really odd and I'm stumped. Is there any issue with the way the input radio buttons are implemented? Any issues between the ng-model/ng-checked/ng-value/ng-click?

I am using angular-touch and fastclick.js. Is this an issue with the combination of fastclick.js and angular touch? This issue seems to be coming only for this particular module, as touch works fine for the rest of the modules...

Answer (score 1):

Ok found the issue and the solution. On desktops, browsers render the label as the same area as the radio button, but on mobile Safari, only the actual area of the input radio button is considered to be valid. I resolved this issue by

```
<div class="buyBox" id="{{bBox.id}}" ng-repeat="bBox in bBoxProps" ng-class="{disabledBb: bBox.disabled, invalidBb: bBox.invalid}">
            <div class="bbTitle"><h3>{{bBox.title | uppercase}}</h3></div>
            <div class="bbSelect">
                <div class="bbSelectTop bbSelectOpt">
                    <input type="radio" name="{{bBox.id}}" id="{{bBox.options[0].optId}}" class="css-checkbox" ng-click="pmFlow(state,this,bBox.options[0])" ng-checked="bBox.options[0].isSelected==true" ng-model="bBox.options[0].isSelected" ng-disabled="bBox.options[0].isDisabled" ng-class="{invalidBbOpt: bBox.options[0].isInvalid}" ng-value="true"/>
                    <label for="{{bBox.options[0].optId}}" class="bbLabel" **ng-click="selectBuyParam($event)"**><div class="bbLabelText">{{bBox.options[0].name}}</div></label>
                </div>
                <div class="buyOr">OR</div>
                <div class="bbSelectBottom bbSelectOpt">
                    <input type="radio" name="{{bBox.id}}" id="{{bBox.options[1].optId}}" class="css-checkbox" ng-click="pmFlow(state,this,bBox.options[1])" ng-checked="bBox.options[1].isSelected==true" ng-model="bBox.options[1].isSelected" ng-disabled="bBox.options[1].isDisabled" ng-class="{invalidBbOpt: bBox.options[1].isInvalid}" ng-value="true"/>
                    <label for="{{bBox.options[1].optId}}" class="bbLabel" **ng-click="selectBuyParam($event)"**><div class="bbLabelText">{{bBox.options[1].name}}</div></label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

By adding a jQuery function to manually trigger click of input upon click of label.

```
$scope.selectBuyParam = function(event){
    var clickTarget = $(event.target).parents('.bbSelectOpt').children('input.css-checkbox');
    $timeout(function() {
    angular.element(clickTarget).triggerHandler('click');
  }, 100);
  };
```